# Time Difference in Two Formats

Tags: php, date, time, laravel, php-carbon

I have two time values that I want to take difference of. First is coming from a database, and it looks like "2014-05-13 10:41:09". It's in `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` format. But it's a `Carbon` object.

I have another time, which is now. I get it like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

I want to take the difference of those two times. First, I wanted to get `now()` in Carbon. But I can't. I don't know why. So I tried to transform my `Carbon` object to PHP Date object. I couldn't either.

But I dumped and died the Carbon object. It looks like this:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#225 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-05-13 10:41:09" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "Europe/City" }
```

The date I want to access is in ["date"] part.

How can I take the difference of those two times?

This is the output of those two days:

> 2014-05-13 10:46:09
>
> 2014-05-13 10:46:20

EDIT:

Here's the output of:

```
var_dump($unit->heartbeat);
die;

object(Carbon\Carbon)#225 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-05-13 10:59:09" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(15) "Europe" }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why can't you use `$CarbonObject->date` to get the date from the object? Try var_dumping it, maybe it's private?

Comment: Are you trying to get the difference in time between two dates here?

Comment: The way you've composed your question suggests that you are using a dedicated date library that doesn't have a function to generate current date. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @Bryan I can't. Because this is Laravel. And if I use $object->date, Laravel will try to access the "date" value of $object from database. And, there's no "date" value in database. I think I had to add laravel to the question. My bad.

Comment: @ksealey Yes. I want to check whether those two time values are 5 minutes close. I mean, I want to check whether date1 - date2 < 5 minutes.

Comment: @citizen_of_noobville I'm unfamiliar with Larvel, how are you supposed to access public instance variables? Would you mind posting a var_dump so we can see the structure of the object?

Comment: @Bryan I added the output to question.

Comment: That's not what a `var_dump` should look like...Unless the only things in the object are those 3 instance variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I wanted to get now() in Carbon. But I can't. I don't know why.

The [Instantiation](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-instantiation) section of the Carbon manual provides these examples:

```
$carbon = new Carbon();                  // equivalent to Carbon::now()
$now = Carbon::now();
```

They're equivalent, so you have to pick one rather than using both.

You already have a powerful dedicated data type for dates—you should make use of it. Thus this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

... serves no real purpose and only adds confusion.

As about getting differences, there's a whole [Difference](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-difference) chapter in the manual. It should be pretty straightforward once you use the appropriate types.

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for your reply. I added Carbon namespace on the top of my page, and it works now. However, the diffInSeconds() function does not work. I tried the example stated in that link. The time difference between Vancouver and London. Function outputs 0. Do you know why did it happen? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I saw my mistake. It says it should be 0.

Comment: Of course: **now** is the same moment in time, in London or Vancouver. Neither Canada nor Britain move close to the speed of light :)